# reading/ accessing/importing a database file into r

Tags: r

I hope everyone is doing well I am trying to read/import a database file to  R which have extension of .db but I am not able to do so. I search for the related material but not able to find the answer. the data file is about Wikipedia article contents and is quite huge file. so any help would be very helpful . 
I tried the this method as well
[Import .db file into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256498/import-db-file-into-r)
 but got the same error and the proposed answer was difficult to understand for me as I am new to  R .

```
library(project template) 
x<-db.reader("wiki.db,"H:\\wiki.db","wiki.db") 
Error: could not find function "db.reader"
```

so as suggested in the above post I applied the answer to run the function as

```
db.reader <- function(data.file, filename, variable.name)
    {    
  require.package('RSQLite')
  sqlite.driver <- dbDriver("SQLite")

  connection <- dbConnect(sqlite.driver,    
                          dbname = filename)

  tables <- dbListTables(connection)    
  for (table in tables)
  {
    message(paste('  Loading table:', table))
    data.parcel <- dbReadTable(connection,
                               table,
                               row.names = NULL)
    assign(clean.variable.name(table),data.parcel,envir = .TargetEnv)
  }
  disconnect.success <- dbDisconnect(connection)

  if (! disconnect.success)
   {
    warning(paste('Unable to disconnect from database:', filename))
   }  
}
```

but now I get error as

```
Loading table: FArevisionContentPlain

Error in  assign(clean.variable.name(table), data.parcel, envir = .TargetEnv)  
  could not find function "clean.variable.name"
```

any help would be highly appreciated and will be very helpful to me.

Comment: what is the database you trying to connect?

Comment: its Db file with .db extension and it contain the text data about the wikipedia article .

Comment: maybe this could help? http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/ProjectTemplate/html/db.reader.html

Comment: I tried this as I mentioned it in the post as well but I got the error of could not find function db.reader

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: library(project template)                                                                                      x<-db.reader("wiki.db,"H:\\wiki.db","wiki.db")                                                                Error: could not find function "db.reader"

Comment: for one thing it's library(ProjectTemplate), and did you make sure it was installed and loaded.

Comment: yes I think it is installed and loaded as after using Library(ProjectTemplate) it says                                                                   package ‘ProjectTemplate’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import .db file into R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256498/import-db-file-into-r)

Comment: i think I mentioned this in the post as well , and the suggested answer is difficult for me to understand. so should I just copy paste the suggested code and then use the above library and function?

Comment: You should be able to copy and paste the code and then you won't need the ProjectTemplate library. You can just run the code. Run the function code provided and then run the line to call the function.

Comment: now I got this error        Loading table: FArevisionContentPlain
Error in assign(clean.variable.name(table), data.parcel, envir = .TargetEnv) : 
  could not find function "clean.variable.name"

Comment: clean.variable.name is still a function inside the 'ProjectTemplate' library. See [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ProjectTemplate/docs/clean.variable.name). Even though you used the source code from the other solution to create a new function, you still need to load the library(ProjectTemplate) because the function you defined has dependencies on it. You can view the source code for the function [here](https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/ProjectTemplate/blob/master/R/clean.variable.name.R). If need be you can utilize this to resolve the issue as we did above.

Comment: i don't know how to solve this issue , I have no experience of programming

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your db file to test this with but if you are having problems with the library the source code is available [here](https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/ProjectTemplate). Again I can not test this but based on your comments above you could do the following:

```
my.db.reader <- function(data.file, filename, variable.name)
{
  require.package('RSQLite')

  sqlite.driver <- dbDriver("SQLite")
  connection <- dbConnect(sqlite.driver,
                          dbname = filename)

  tables <- dbListTables(connection)
  for (table in tables)
  {
    message(paste('  Loading table:', table))

    data.parcel <- dbReadTable(connection,
                               table,
                               row.names = NULL)

    assign(clean.variable.name(table),
           data.parcel,
           envir = .TargetEnv)
  }

  disconnect.success <- dbDisconnect(connection)
  if (! disconnect.success)
  {
    warning(paste('Unable to disconnect from database:', filename))
  }
}
clean.variable.name <- function(variable.name)
{
  variable.name <- gsub('^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', variable.name, perl = TRUE)
  variable.name <- gsub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$', '', variable.name, perl = TRUE)
  variable.name <- gsub('_+', '.', variable.name, perl = TRUE)
  variable.name <- gsub('-+', '.', variable.name, perl = TRUE)
  variable.name <- gsub('\\s+', '.', variable.name, perl = TRUE)
  variable.name <- gsub('\\.+', '.', variable.name, perl = TRUE)
  variable.name <- gsub('[\\\\/]+', '.', variable.name, perl = TRUE)
  variable.name <- make.names(variable.name)
  return(variable.name)
}

x<-my.db.reader("wiki.db,"H:\\wiki.db","wiki.db")
```

This is simply the source code used to define two functions. The last line is how you can call the function you just created using the parameters you specified in your original question.

Comment: I run the code as mentioned above but again the same problem like  Loading table: FArevisionContentPlain
Error in assign(clean.variable.name(table), data.parcel, envir = .TargetEnv) : 
  object '.TargetEnv' not found

Answer (score 0):

`clean.variable.name` is a function in the `ProjectManager` package that cleans up the filename of the table in your specified database. For example, it turns a database table named `data_table` into `data.table`.

`.TargetEnv` is a variable within the `ProjectManager` package that points to `.GlobalVariable` (see [here](https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/ProjectTemplate/issues/138)). So if you are putting the `db.reader` in your code manually, this variable will not be found.

To prevent these errors, you can ignore needing to use `clean.variable.name`, and also specify your own environment variable:

```
e <- new.env()

custom.db.reader <- function(data.file, filename, variable.name) {
  require.package('RSQLite')
  sqlite.driver <- dbDriver("SQLite")
  connection <- dbConnect(sqlite.driver, dbname = filename)
  tables <- dbListTables(connection)
  for (table in tables) {
    message(paste('  Loading table:', table))
    data.parcel <- dbReadTable(connection, table, row.names = NULL)
    assign(table, data.parcel, envir = e)
  }
  disconnect.success <- dbDisconnect(connection)
  if (! disconnect.success) {
    warning(paste('Unable to disconnect from database:', filename))
  }
}
```

You can then access the imported database table, if the database table is named `data_table`, at `e$data_table`.